# Securing invalid login attempts with Google Recaptcha v3

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I read the documents but struggling to understand how Recaptcha v3 will secure login page if there are numerous times of password error.

Will Recaptcha notice this when a user (even having high score) who forgot their password has made too many incorrect login attempts?

Should I do some extra code work or Recaptcha will handle it?